# What is the standard setup for a standalone java application with GUI

Tags: java, user-interface, serialization

I am doing an Java application that takes some input and generate loads of output and plot them to graphs(`JFreeChart`). I have all the functionality I need working and a console app that use a simple `while(true)` loop to keep asking for input(via `System.in`), the graphs would pop up when it is generated.

Now I would like to build it into a user-friendly GUI app and be able to save the states/data like all the other desktop applications. 
So what is the standard setup or design that people use to build an standalone GUI app that can save data?

I am thinking of: 
`java.swing` for GUI and serialize the objects into xml

Not sure if this would be a good design and how would they link with each others. I read something about JavaBeans and Spring Framework but I am not sure if I need them.

Comment: Swing is fine, though some prefer JavaFX. For data persistence you need a database.  Something like MySQL would do.

Answer (score -1):

The best way to make this sounds like using a `JFrame`. Code using `JFrame`, like any have code can `import java.io`. You want to stick to the simple `Javax.swing` classes like `JButton` and `JLabel` to make your GUI.

XML is a powerful tool and easy to read. I recommend using it with SAX. There is no need to use `JavaBeans` or `Spring`. You may want to use your GUI fork input instead of the standard `system.in`. This can easily be done with `Javax.swing`.